# File disappears after multi-file upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I've made an upload form for an admin page within Codeigniter that uploads a new HTML form and relevant PHP files into a database for users to access

I can select several files to upload but one of my files will not upload and I can't understand why - even if I try to upload it individually. Below I've included the HTML upload form, the codeigniter controller and the contents of the file that won't upload. All the other files will upload.

**The Upload Form**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="white-box">
      <h3 class="box-title m-b-0">Resource Upload Form</h3>
      <p class="text-muted m-b-30 font-13"> Upload your resource to the live database </p>

      <form class="form-horizontal" id="uploadForm" action="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/do_uploads" method="post" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>

          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Upload Resource</legend>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="resource_name">Resource Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input id="resource_name" name="resource_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>
              <span class="help-block">Name of the resource that is being uploaded</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Textarea -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="resource_description">Resource Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="resource_description" name="resource_description"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- File Button -->
          <!-- Form -->

          <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="year_group">Year Group</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-0">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-0" value="1"> 1
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-1" value="2"> 2
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-2" value="3"> 3
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-3">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-3" value="4"> 4
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-4">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-4" value="5"> 5
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-5">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-5" value="6"> 6
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-6">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-6" value="eyfs"> EYFS
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-7">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-7" value="ks1"> KS1
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-8">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-8" value="ks2"> KS2
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-9">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-9" value="lks2"> LKS2
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-10">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-10" value="uks2"> UKS2
                            </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="year_group-11">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="year_group" id="year_group-11" value="all"> All
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subscriber_level">Subscriber Level</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="radio-inline" for="subscriber_level-0">
                                <input type="radio" name="subscriber_level" id="subscriber_level-0" value="free" checked="checked"> Free
                            </label>
              <label class="radio-inline" for="subscriber_level-1">
                                <input type="radio" name="subscriber_level" id="subscriber_level-1" value="basic"> Basic
                            </label>
              <label class="radio-inline" for="subscriber_level-2">
                                <input type="radio" name="subscriber_level" id="subscriber_level-2" value="premium"> Premium
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="resource_name">Resource Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input type="file" name="userfiles[]" size="20" multiple />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit">Submit</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <br />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Upload Controller**

```
function do_uploads($page = "")
    {
        $createDirName = uniqid();
        $dirName = 'application/views/resources/' . $createDirName;
        mkdir($dirName);
        $config['upload_path'] = $dirName;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|php';
        //$config['max_size'] = '1024';
        //$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        var_dump($_FILES['userfiles']);

        $fileInfos = array();
        $errors = array();
        if (! empty($_FILES['userfiles']['name'])) {
            $photosCount = count($_FILES['userfiles']['name']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $photosCount; $i ++) {
                // Create file upload info
                $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $_FILES['userfiles']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $_FILES['userfiles']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfiles']['size'][$i];
                $data['fileName'] = $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
                //$mode = 0777;
                //chmod(base_url() . $dirName, octdec($mode));
                // Upload file to server
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                    array_push($fileInfos, array(
                        'userfile' => $this->upload->data()
                    ));
                } else {
                    array_push($errors, array(
                        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors(),
                        'count' => $photosCount,
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Contents of the file that won't Upload with the above: index.php**

```html
<form class="needs-validation" id="questionsform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/loadSheet/additionWorksheets/generator" method="post" name="form">
  Choose the maximum number of digits for the top number.<br />
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="1"> 1</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="2"> 2</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="3"> 3</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="4"> 4</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="5"> 5</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="6"> 6</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="topNumber" value="7"> 7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  Choose the maximum number of digits for the bottom number. <br />
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="1"> 1</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="2"> 2</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="3"> 3</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="4"> 4</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="5"> 5</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="6"> 6</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="bottomNumber" value="7"> 7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input id="toHide" type="radio" name="calculation" value="addition" checked="checked"><br>

  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: *but one of my files will not upload* sorry, I'm late, but which extension has the file causing the upload error?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, uploading some .php files were ok, but some weren't. I'm not sure what is going on in Codeigniter that makes this happen but I solved the problem by changing

```php
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|php';
```

to

```php
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

This is not an ideal solution as I don't want all files available to upload but this is only an admin user function, so I'm happy for now.